# Setting up httpd.conf / mod_rewrite to redirect to codeigniter?

Tags: apache, codeigniter, ssh

I'm sorry to ask this here, as I'm sure the solution is fairly easy but for the life of my I can't setup httpd.conf on my localhost apache server to automatically load the codeigniter files.

Instead I'm having to go into the folder itself localhost/trunk/etc/etc until I get index.php - which messes with some of the relative paths (our backend coder is gone for the week so I can't ask him, but he has already setup the rewrite rules on our development server).

Can someone tell me how to setup httpd.conf and mod_rewrite on my local environment so going to http://localhost goes straight into codeigniter's index.php?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. You say he has already set up the rewrite rules, so what exactly do you need?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  The develop setup the files on the development/production server - I'm trying to set them up locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mess with httpd.conf, look for the Document Root line:

DocumentRoot "/path/to/CI/folder"

save it, and restart apache.

If you plan on changing httpd.conf MAKE A BACKUP OF IT FIRST. I've messed up many installs changing things around and regretted not backing up the file first :)

And you'll need to adjust the CI conf settings with path info etc. after changing httpd.conf