# .htaccess file causing forbidden error in my codeigniter application, I am running apache 24 in my windows server

Tags: windows, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

Without the .htaccess file the application running perfectly, 
Whenever I add .htaccess file it showing forbidden don't have access to the / server.
I tried to put "Test." in the first line of .htaccess file it "showing Internal server error" that's good apache reading .htaccess file.
But whenever it read "RewriteEngine on" line in .htaccess file immediately it showing forbidden error.

here is my .htaccess file.

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And httpd.config file

```
   DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
   <Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
   #
   # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
   # or any combination of:
   #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
   #
   # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
   # doesn't give it to you.
   #
   # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
   # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
   # for more information.
   #
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

   #
   # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
   # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
   #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
   #
   AllowOverride All

   #
   # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
   #
   Require all granted
   Options ExecCGI 
   </Directory>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551840/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)

Comment: I have tried the following example but still, my problem is not solved

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no need to change `httpd.conf` file, `.htaccess` file is
   enough to make your `CI` project up and running.
2. But if you must, you need to give absolute path in `DocumentRoot` ie change `${SRVROOT}/htdocs` to
   `"F:/xampp/htdocs" -- (your/location/here)`
3. `${SRVROOT}` will not work as you are not writing in a `.php` file.

See these for more info --

- [How to set codeigniter for apache server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273975/how-to-set-codeigniter-for-apache-server)
- [Setting up httpd.conf / mod_rewrite to redirect to codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033110/setting-up-httpd-conf-mod-rewrite-to-redirect-to-codeigniter)
- [How to correct config Apache and Codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272182/how-to-correct-config-apache-and-codeigniter)

This is my `httpd.conf` file -

```
DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "F:/xampp/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

my `.htaccess` -

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1  
# if your base_url() doesn't have a trailing slash then instead of ↑ use ↓- 
# RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/$1
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: No, It possible to create dynamic ServerRoot
And ${SRVROOT} is part of the syntax, Not PHP variable.
please check the link for more details 
https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=36957

Comment: what is `${SRVROOT}` defined with? @harsha

Comment: Define SRVROOT "C:/Apache24"
ServerRoot "${SRVROOT}"
Way to declare  dynamic path in httpd.conf 
So whenever I call ${SRVROOT} it will call the C:/Apache24

Comment: are you using xampp?

Comment: No directly installed apache and php 7.0, I have other projects from scriptcase are running on that server,
So some one from my team modified the httpd.conf and php.ini file according to scriptcase

Comment: I've updated my httpd.conf file in the answer. If it doesn't get your project to run then I don't think the error is due to `httpd.conf` file

Comment: Without .htaccess file i am able to run my project, with .htaccess file it showing forbidden don't have access to the /mpnsearch/ server